# How to read only number from a specific line in file using shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

i want to write a shell script to read only number from each line in a file and store it in variable. file from which i must read is like this

```
file1.txt
 Current Offset from Master : 939
 Current Offset from Master : 27256
```

Comment: Do all the files have the same format (as in, words and then a colon and then your number)?

Comment: yes. the format is same

Answer (score 3):

You can grep the numbers, and then loop through them and do whatever you want

```
cat file1.txt | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

or simply

```
grep -o '[0-9]*' file1.txt
```

so your shell script could look like

```
for x in `grep -o '[0-9]*' file1.txt`;
do
 # do something with $x
done
```

Comment: what if we pass the filename as inline arguments ie sh file.sh file.txt

Comment: these are called "positional arguments": 
     `for x in \`grep -o '[0-9]*' $1\`;`

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
for line in $(cat file.txt)
do
   offset="${line//[^0-9]/}"
done
```